# Copy another worksheet if the main references it in formulas, Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that references another worksheet in the same workbook "ProductsList". The VBA should save the worksheet as stand alone spreadsheet and if any formula contains references to my Products list should save it along as well.

I am trying to use the following:

```
Function UsesProductsList(ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim r As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set r = ws.UsedRange
    UsesProductsList = False
    For Each c In r
        If InStr(1, c.Formula, ProductsList.Name) > 0 Then
            UsesProductsList = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next c
End Function
```

but having an error. When I am debugging the error I can see that that it has something to do with the following line `If InStr(1, c.Formula, ProductsList.Name) > 0 Then` and when I am hovering over with mouse I can see the formula that I have in the cell `A1`.

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Run-time error 424 Object Required

Comment: ```ProductsList.Name``` might be the reason. If the "ProductsList" a name of a workbook is, then use ```Workbooks``` collection like this : ```Workbooks("ProductsList").Worksheets(1).Name``` ... or any name of the sheet : ```Workbooks("ProductsList").Worksheets("SomeSheetName").Name```

Comment: Like how? I just thought that if the specified name exist in the formulas VBA should recognise it and continue with saving.

Comment: ProductsList is the name of one of the worksheets

Comment: So it is hard to say what your proble is. Check ```ProductsList.Name```. If the ```ProductsList``` is a name of the sheet it should work. Didn't you misspelled the name of it? Try e.g. ```InStr(1, c.Formula, "TheName")```. Use ```Option Explicit``` at the very beginning, this helps a lot.

Comment: It was my fault, I have not done it correctly and thanks for pointing this out to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in the comments that "ProductsList is the name of one of the worksheets". VBA doesn't automatically know what things in your workbook are named. So you have to use code like `Workbooks("book_name")` and `Worksheets("sheet_name")` where book_name and sheet_name get replaced by the actual name. So you need to change this code:

```
If InStr(1, c.Formula, ProductsList.Name) > 0 Then
```

To either

```
If InStr(1, c.Formula, "ProductsList") > 0 Then
```

Or

```
If InStr(1, c.Formula, Worksheets("ProductsList").Name) > 0 Then
```

Both of these end up with the name being hard-coded in the function. You could also change the definition of the function to:

```
Function UsesProductsList(ws As Worksheet, wsProductList As Worksheet) As Boolean
```

and then you change the line of code to:

```
If InStr(1, c.Formula, wsProductsList.Name) > 0 Then
```

When you use the `UsesProductsList` function you will need to include the parameter for the ProductsList sheet. You can use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ProductsList")` or `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ProductsList")`